# Change navigationbar and cancel button for google cast views

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

I've implemented the google cast framework in my project and start theming the google cast views.

At the moment i've this piece of code:

```
let castStyle = GCKUIStyle.sharedInstance()

//DeviceChooser
castStyle.castViews.deviceControl.deviceChooser.backgroundColor = theme.googleCastDeviceChooserBackgroundColor
castStyle.castViews.deviceControl.deviceChooser.iconTintColor = theme.googleCastDeviceChooserIconTintColor
castStyle.castViews.deviceControl.deviceChooser.headingTextColor = theme.googleCastDeviceChooserHeadingTextColor
castStyle.castViews.deviceControl.deviceChooser.captionTextColor = theme.googleCastDeviceChooserCaptionTextColor
castStyle.castViews.deviceControl.deviceChooser.headingTextFont = theme.googleCastDeviceChooserHeadingTextFont
castStyle.castViews.deviceControl.deviceChooser.captionTextFont = theme.googleCastDeviceChooserCaptionTextFont

UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = theme.googleCastNavigationBarBackgroundColor
UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.red
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: theme.googleCastNavigationBarIconTintColor]
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.green], for: .normal)
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red], for: .selected)

castStyle.apply()
```

I still have some problems with the styling of the devicechooser:

- Navigationbar cancel button is not changing of color
       --> The backgroundcolor of the navigation bar did change to the correct color.
- Don't seem to find a way to style the separator color of the tableview.